# If $A_1, A_2, A_3$ are disjoint circles in the complex plane, prove there is a fourth circle or line that is perpendicular to all.

Tags: complex-analysis

> If $A_1, A_2, A_3$ are disjoint circles in the complex plane, prove there is a fourth circle or line that is perpendicular to $A_1, A_2, A_3$.

To start off, I can see this is clearly true if $A_1$ and $A_2$ are concentric. But in the general case, how can we show this is true? Perhaps there is a way with conformal mappings?

Comment: what does it mean for two circles to be perpendicular? or did you mean tangent?

Answer (score 0):

With a conformal mapping, we can make two of the circles concentric. 
Consider inversions about points on the line joining the centres of these circles.

Comment: Any details on this? This seems tricky. How does the $C_3$ perform under the transformation to concentric circles?

Comment: Invert if necessary, rotate, translate and scale so the first circle is centred at $0$ with radius $1$, the second is inside the first and centred at $b$ with radius $r$, $-1 < b-r < b+r < 1$.  If we invert about $x$, $b-r < x < b+r$, the image of the first circle has centre $c_1 = \dfrac{x}{1-x^2}$ while the image of the second has centre $c_2 = \dfrac{b-x}{(b-x)^2  - r^2}$.  These are continuous functions of $x \in (b-r,b+r)$, and $c_2$ has limits $+\infty$ and $-\infty$ as $x$ approaches the endpoints of that interval, while $c_1$ stays bounded.  Use the Intermediate Value Theorem.